# Renaming keys in firebase with multiple sub-keys

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an activity in which I am allowing the user to change his UserPIN(immediate key under Attendance_Records table), and I have read that there is no way to update Firebase Realtime Database other than removing and adding the data with updation again. My problem is I have to update the key in a table but it has multiple sub-keys and a lot of data. How can I access the sub-keys and store them? Won't the data updation take a lot of time?

Suppose I have to update the key:123452

**Attendance_Records Table**

[image]

**I am all ears if there is any other way of doing it, apart from what I have tried below**

**EDIT**

I have achieved the level where I am able to retrieve the data from the Attendance_Records table by using:

```
rootRefAttTable = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                  .getReference("Attendance_Records")
                                  .child(carriedmPIN);
newRefAttTable = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                 .getReference("Attendance_Records");
attRec = new Attendance_Records();
```

then

```
private void changeAttTable(){
Log.d("abcd","changeAttTable() reached");

rootRefAttTable.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

            for(DataSnapshot yearsnap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                yearKey = yearsnap.getKey();
                Log.d("abcd","yearKey is: "+yearKey);

                monthkeyRef = rootRefAttTable.child(yearKey);
                monthkeyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                            for(DataSnapshot monthsnap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                monthKey = monthsnap.getKey();

                                datekeyRef = monthkeyRef.child(monthKey);
                                datekeyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                                            for(DataSnapshot datesnap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                                dateKey = datesnap.getKey();


                                                date = datesnap.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                                                enteryDate = datesnap.child("entryDate").getValue(String.class);
                                                inTime = datesnap.child("inTime").getValue(String.class);
                                                month = datesnap.child("month").getValue(String.class);
                                                myID = datesnap.child("myID").getValue(String.class);
                                                outTime = datesnap.child("outTime").getValue(String.class);
                                                status = datesnap.child("status").getValue(String.class);
                                                year = datesnap.child("year").getValue(String.class);

                                                addDataAttTable();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}

private void getValuesAtt(){
Log.d("abcd","getValuesAtt() reached");

attRec.setYear(year);
attRec.setMonth(month);
attRec.setMyID(myID);
attRec.setEntryDate(enteryDate);
attRec.setStatus(status);
attRec.setOutTime(outTime);
attRec.setInTime(inTime);
attRec.setDate(date);
}

private void addDataAttTable(){
Log.d("abcd","addDataAttTable() reached");

getValuesAtt();
newRefAttTable.child(carriedmPIN).removeValue();
newRefAttTable.child(enterednewmpin).child(yearKey).child(monthKey).child(dateKey).setValue(attRec);
}
```

But, the addition to database is not in the way it should have been:

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Sorry about the before updation image. After updation(123450 to 123459), the months 3 and 4 are joined together, and for now I don't have 2 years(2018 and 2019 suppose) else I think they would also have joined. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did it!!

Sometimes you think for deeper logics but what is required is just a simple code!

I did it by:

```
rootRefAttTable = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attendance_Records").child(carriedmPIN);

newRefAttTable = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attendance_Records");
```

carriedmPIN is the PIN user needs to change.

```
private void changeAttTable() {

    Log.d("abcd","changeAttTable() reached");

     rootRefAttTable.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             for(DataSnapshot yearsnap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                for(DataSnapshot monthsnap:yearsnap.getChildren()){
                    for(DataSnapshot datesnap:monthsnap.getChildren()){
                        dateAtt = datesnap.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("abcd","date is: "+dateAtt);
                        entrydateAtt = datesnap.child("entryDate").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("abcd","enteryDate is: "+entrydateAtt);
                        intimeAtt = datesnap.child("inTime").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("abcd","inTime is: "+intimeAtt);
                        monthAtt = datesnap.child("month").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("abcd","month is: "+monthAtt);
                        myidAtt = datesnap.child("myID").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("abcd","myID is: "+myidAtt);
                        outtimeAtt = datesnap.child("outTime").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("abcd","outTime is: "+outtimeAtt);
                        statusAtt = datesnap.child("status").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("abcd","status is: "+statusAtt);
                        yearAtt = datesnap.child("year").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("abcd","year is: "+yearAtt);

                        getValuesAtt();
                        newRefAttTable.child(enterednewmpin).child(yearsnap.getKey()).child(monthsnap.getKey()).child(datesnap.getKey()).setValue(attRec);
                    }
                }

             }
         newRefAttTable.child(carriedmPIN).removeValue();
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

         }

     });

}

private void getValuesAtt(){
    Log.d("abcd","getValuesAtt() reached");

    attRec.setYear(yearAtt);
    attRec.setMonth(monthAtt);
    attRec.setMyID(myidAtt);
    attRec.setEntryDate(entrydateAtt);
    attRec.setStatus(statusAtt);
    attRec.setOutTime(outtimeAtt);
    attRec.setInTime(intimeAtt);
    attRec.setDate(dateAtt);
}
```

I am just so happy!! I was stuck on this since a long time!! :P

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem here is that the `monthKey` is common which is **04** if I get it right, so by default Firebase consider it as the same child and will add everything under.

But back to the main question, **Changing the pin**, did you try this:

**EDIT:**
Why don't you maybe change the structure of your database by using the unique id Firebase provide to each child added and use it as a key, then add a field in your child for the pin?

This will first of all make sure all your childs won't conflict later on if you have users with common PINs, second it will make it a lot easier to retrieve the whole user object on a temp object, change the PIN value in it, then push it again to the same child using the unique id provided!

If you're wondering how to get catch of this unique id, I also recommend saving it as a field in your object, save it while pushing your object, and retrieve from the retrieved temp object whenever needed.

Best way to handle all this is through the `onChildAdded` and `onChildChanged` methods not manually *(**HINT:** Try to split your DB into different references, that will make it easier for you to manage `ChildListener`)*

Comment: I think directly using setValue won't work as it will at most just rename my key and all the children will be deleted.

Comment: Yes I just checked it, I am sure there is a way around just to change a specific value though, or maybe change the database structure, like saving the pin as a field in the object?

Comment: Hey! I checked it before, there is no way to rename anything in Firebase, we need to remove and set the value again. It is easy to do for less complicated database but mine has multiple levels :/

Comment: I can't change the DB structure, as according to this PIN only I am letting the users view their attendance monthly.

Comment: [This video series] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o&index=0&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) should clarify the idea that when it comes to NoSQL DB you need to head towards the flat structures, hope it will help!
However in your case, if you insist of saving your structure as it is, I guess by adding the PIN field you and using the provided key of Firebase, you can extract in `onChildAddded` a list of PIN and key, then through the user entering the PIN you get your object from the DB using the key linked to it. *(still I guess you need to think about PIN duplications)*